# How does one angle axis transform a vector to match the direction of another?

Tags: java, math, matrix

I am making a space game for a school project and my ships' AI rely on the ability to move towards another ship. My current implementation does not work because it rotates the ship to both directions of my destination vector, so occasionally it attacking ship will go in the exact opposite direction, while other times it will go the correct direction. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
//ship heading (already calculated)
Vector3f heading /* = ... */;
heading.normalize();

//direction of enemy ship relative to ours
Vector3d direction = new Vector3f(enemy.x - ship.x, enemy.y - ship.y, enemy.z - ship.z);
direction.normalize();

//angle between vectors
float angle = heading.angle(direction);

//axis to rotate upon
Vector3f axis = new Vector3f();
axis.cross(heading, direction);
axis.normalize();

//initialize matrix to hold rotation
Matrix4f rot = new Matrix4f();
rot.setIdentity();

//rotate the ship if we are more than 10 deg off
if (angle > Math.toRadians(10)) {
    rot.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(axis, rotationVelocity * deltaTime));
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what's wrong, and include examples of when the code works and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I have figured out a better way to do it, which involves some linear interpolation.

The following still remains the same:

```
//ship heading (already calculated)
Vector3f heading /* = ... */;
heading.normalize();

//direction of enemy ship relative to ours
Vector3d direction = new Vector3f(enemy.x - ship.x, enemy.y - ship.y, enemy.z - ship.z);
direction.normalize();

//angle between vectors
float angle = heading.angle(direction);
```

Now I calculate the percent of heading vector to be interpolated to the direction vector:

```
//calculate angle to rotate
float deltaRotation = rotationVelocity * deltaTime;

//calcuate percent of rotation 
float percent = Math.min(deltaRotation / angle, 1.0f);

//create interpolated vector representing the new forward direction
Vector3f inter = new Vector3f(heading.x + percent * (direction.x - heading.x), heading.y + percent * (direction.y - heading.y), heading.z + percent * (direction.z - heading.z));
inter.normalize();
```

Now we can create the new rotation matrix:

```
//the object's default forward size without any transformations
Vector3f forward = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

//rotation axis
Vector3f axis = new Vector3f();
axis.cross(forward, inter);
axis.normalize();

//New rotation matrix to be applied
Matrix4f rotationMatrix = new Matrix4f();
rotationMatrix.setIdentity();
rotationMatrix.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(axis, forward.angle(inter)));
```

Now my ship always faces the correct direction! :)